# Can't insert my records into database?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my register form,after i add validation and my record can't insert into database.But my validation are working.If i exchange the code of validation and mysql,all can insert into database even if got error in my validation.

```
<?php
$fnameErr=$lnameErr=$passErr=$repassErr=$icErr=$emailErr=$add1Err=$add2Err=$postErr=$mobileErr="";
$fname=$lname=$pass=$repass=$ic=$email=$add1=$add2=$postcode=$mobile="";

if (isset($_POST['submitbtn']))
{
    $fname    = $_POST['bname'];
    $lname    = $_POST['lname'];
    $pass     = $_POST['bpass'];
    $repass   = $_POST['bconpass'];
    $ic       = $_POST['bic'];
    $email    = $_POST['bemail'];
    $add1     = $_POST['badd1'];
    $add2     = $_POST['badd2'];
    $postcode = $_POST['bpostcode'];
    $mobile   = $_POST['bmobile'];
    $country  = $_POST['bcountry'];
    $state    = $_POST['bstate'];
    $city     = $_POST['bcity'];
    $gen      = $_POST['bgender'];

        if($fname==""||$lname==""||$pass==""||$repass==""||$ic==""||$email==""||$add1==""||$add2==""||$country==""||$state==""||$postcode==""||$mobile==""||$city==""||$gen=="")                 
    {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Please fill in all the required informations.");
        </script>
    <?php
    }


 if (empty($errors) === true)
    {

            //bemail
            if (filter_var($_POST['bemail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) 
            {
                $emailErr = 'A valid email address is required';

            }
            else if (email_exists($_POST['bemail']) === true) 
            {
                $emailErr= 'Sorry, the email \'' . $_POST['bemail'] . '\' is already in use';

            }

            //fname xx
            if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/i",$_POST['bname'])) 
            {
                $fnameErr= 'Your first name cannot contain with any symbol and number';

            }

            //lname xx
            if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/i",$_POST['lname']) )
            {
                $lnameErr= 'Your last name cannot contain with any symbol and number';

            }
            //ic xx
            if(!preg_match("/^\d{6}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/i", $_POST['bic'])) 
            {
                $icErr= 'Your ic cannot contain any character / must insert "-"';

            }
            //mobile xx
            if (!preg_match("/^\d{3}-\d{7}$/i", $_POST['bmobile'])) 
            {
                $mobileErr= 'Phone must comply with this mask: 010-1111111 or 0111-1111111';

            }
            //password
            if (strlen($pass) < 6) 
            {
                $passErr = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters';

            }

            //re-password
            if ($_POST['bpass'] !== $_POST['bconpass']) 
            {
                $repassErr= 'Your password do not match';

            }

            //add1 xx
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.,:\"\']+$/i", $_POST['badd1'])) 
            {
                $add1Err = 'Address 1 must be only letters, numbers or one of the following';

            }

            //add2 xx
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.,:\"\']+$/i",$_POST['badd2'])) 
            {
                $add2Err= 'Address 2 must be only letters, numbers or one of the following';

            }

            //postcode xx
            if (!preg_match("/^\d{5}$/i", $_POST['bpostcode'])) 
            {
                $postErr = 'Postcode must be 5 digits';

            }   

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Register have some error,please complete your informations.");
        </script>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {

        $result = mysql_query("select * from member where Member_Email='$email'");                                                 
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
        {
            mysql_query("insert into member(Member_Name,Member_Lname,Member_Pass,Member_IC,Member_Email,Member_Street1,Member_Street2,Member_Country,Member_State,Member_Postcode,Member_HP,Member_City,Member_Gen) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$pass','$ic','$email','$add1','$add2','$country','$state','$postcode','$mobile','$city','$gen')");
            header("Location:all_login.php");           

        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('Registered successfully!');
            </script>
        <?php
        }

        else
        {
?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("email address already exists!");                                                                           
            </script>
<?php
        }
    }   

}       
?>
```

I'm so sorry with my poor english.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Are you getting an error from the server?

Comment: You are doing some filtering on your user input, but nevertheless I think the allowed characters for some of the address elements are sufficient to allow a SQL injection through to the database. This script therefore will probably get hacked, unless you properly escape your user input.

Comment: When fill in incorrect record,will pop up validation and when fill in the correct records,no have any error,but  but can't insert into database.

Comment: That whole huge line, `$fnameErr=$lnameErr=$passErr=$repassErr=$icErr=$emailErr=$add1Err=$add2Err=$postErr=$mobileErr="";
$fname=$lname=$pass=$repass=$ic=$email=$add1=$add2=$postcode=$mobile="";
` is totally unnecessary...

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - I dont see anywhere that PHP 5.5.0 or above is in question...**Where do you see that**? Naturally, if user233711 _is_ using  PHP above 5.5.0 he or she could consider, one day, refactoring to PDO or mysqli, but that would not help him or her now...

Comment: **By building SQL with outside variables, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Comment: @meagar if i no have put that code,the error message will not display.

Comment: @davidkonrad how is preventing technical debt and preventing vulnerable code not helping OP now?

Answer (score 0):

`if (empty($errors) === true)`

At no point before this in the code you posted do you define `$errors`. As per [the PHP doc on that function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), if the variable doesn't exist then `empty()` will return true. So unless you've left something out, your code will always enter the first part of the `if` statement and not the second.

I suspect that you want to change that line to `if (empty($errors) === false)` so that you only enter that part of your code if there *is* an error.

Comment: But if change to false mean validation got error also can insert to database.

Answer (score 0):

You should be really carefull for usage of variable like `$test` should be  `'.$test.'` if string. Also you should use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Changing to string concatonation from string injection will not protect from SQL injection. http://bobby-tables.com/php